# Deleting anomalous points in *.lasd using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-10.3, lidar, outlier

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop. I have a raw .las file that I have brought into an ArcGIS .lasd file format.

The raw data has several anomalous points; i.e. the maximum elevation for any point should only be 100 meters but there are perhaps 30 points with an elevation above 1000 meters.

I would like to delete these anomalous points.

The points are unclassified except for "ground".  All others, including the anomalous ones, are "unclassified".

There doesn't seem to be a way to select these, or filter them out and then write a new .las / .lasd file that has eliminated them.

Comment: why not use a LAS layer?

Comment: Thanks but I am going to be doing further work with this file - trying to get tree canopy - and so I really need to get rid of these points all together.

Comment: I have found LASTools, http://rapidlasso.com/  which includes a custom toolbox....the lasheight tool has enabled me to delete the points.

Comment: great, I suggest that you add this as an answer to your own question (with a few additionnal details on how to use the lasheight tool etc) and you'll get my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

As you cited, [lasheight](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lasheight_README.txt) from **LAStools** can do the trick (used from ArcGIS). It says:

> Another alternative is to use the computed height to eliminate
>     points with a particular ground height above or below a threshold ... .

Example:

```
lasheight -i *.las -odix _no_outlier -olas -drop_above 100.0
```

The above example will make a batch call (i.e., with multiple input files), will keep points with height up to 100 units (e.g. 100 meters) above the ground, and will append the suffix name 'no_outlier' in all the output las files.

So, you would need to identify where is the gap between the outliers from the other points, and set the correct threshold value for `-drop_above`.

---

Another option is the native tool from **ArcGIS Desktop** [Locate Outliers](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/locate-outliers.htm):

> Identifies anomalous elevation measurements from ... LAS datasets that exceed a defined range of elevation values ... .

You would set the tool with the `Apply Hard Limit` methot and the `Absolute Z Maximum` parameter equal to 100 meters.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth a thought:
If the undesired points are significantly(or just noticeably) higher than the rest of the data, you can convert to .txt, open in spreadsheet editor, sort z-value column by descending, manually remove all points higher than desired data height, and then convert back to .las